# How to make div go to new line on ipad air?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following two images (see attached). On Ipad Air, the page looks like [image]

I want it to look like

[image]

I'm using

```
<div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-md"></div><div class="col-md"></div></div></div>
```

to create the section attached.

How can I get the section to appear correctly on Ipad AIR using bootstrap.

I want the two columns to tie half the width on desktop.

Answer (score 0):

for your using code, you have two columns in one row so they will both take up half the width.If you want it to look like the second image is under the first image, u need to set the full columns for first image.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">the first image</div>
<div class="col-md-12">the second image</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi forgot to say I want the two columns to take half the width on desktop

Comment: u just need set the<div class=" col-md-12 col-12"> for each image to solve this problem